# In VBA, how do I find if a pivot table has subtotals at top or bottom?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Using VBA I want to find out if a pivot table has subtotals at the top or bottom.

I tried using

```vb
Activesheet.Pivottables(1).xlSubtotalsLocationType
```

but got

> Runtime error 438.

I am trying to save the format of a pivot table so I can restore it at a later time.  I have developed most of the code to save the parameters of a pivot table in an Excel table and restore the pivot table using the saved information.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Update pivottable and pivotfield name as needed
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PivotField").LayoutSubtotalLocation
```

Return value is

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xlAtBottom | 2 | Subtotal will be at the bottom. |
| xlAtTop | 1 | Subtotal will be at the top. |

Microsoft reference document:

> [PivotField.LayoutSubtotalLocation property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.layoutsubtotallocation?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)